# scala + akka http - how to match entire url with path directive

Tags: scala, path, akka, akka-http

I have a url

http://localhost:8080/api/search/lookup?limit=3000&m=airid.appname.mapping{appname=*}

`path("api"/"search"/"lookup?limit=3000&m=appname.server.mapping")` is unavailable

how to match the entire url including parameters and values?

Comment: appname.server.mapping this should contain some value

Answer (score 1):

The part of the url after the '?' is referred to as the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and is technically not part of the path:

> a query string is the part of a uniform resource locator (URL)
>   containing data that does not fit conveniently into a hierarchical
>   path structure

Therefore, you cannot access it using the [path directive](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/path.html#path).  If you want the entire uri then you need [extractUri](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/basic-directives/extractUri.html#extracturi):

```
val myRoute = extractUri { uri =>
  //rest of Route logic
}
```